# How to Load a dependency from EFS into lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I have recently created an EFS instance for my lambda in order to host my project  dependencies since they exceed the 250MB hard cap.  I Managed to get my File system and EC2 up and running with the appropriate permission. I also configured my lamda to use the EFS. Now the only part i am confused about :

How to i import these dependencies from EFS into my lamda code.

Do i use `require()` with absolute path to the module?

Only found tutorials to do it in Python

Comment: You are trying to reinvent the wheel over there. Just [dockerize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-images.html) your Lambda, and you will magically increase your code size limit with a few gigabytes.

Comment: You are right. i was unaware that using docker would up my zip file limit to 10 GB. Thank you for the information. fell free to add as answer for accpetance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ervin Said in the comments, Using Docker was the way to go about this